# Microsoft Access 2007 List Column with relationship value

Tags: ms-access-2007, listcontrol

I am new to access and I cannot understand how to create a list column with a relationship between 2 tables.

I have one table called Persons and the other Interviews. I create a relationship between ID from Persons and Interviews ParentId. When I create a list column (or control) appear all records. Why?

Comment: Found the solution. The table couldnt be splited :)

Answer (score 0):

IN a relational database it will give every instance for all records that have a relationship.  When creating your new query or form, try Select.Distinct